# AFURLSessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest completionHandler not Asynchronous

Tags: ios, asynchronous, afnetworking, completionhandler

While working with the AFNetworking library I am running into an issue where after downloading JSON data into a file using the AFURLSessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest's destination param code block asynchronously, I am wanting to perform the remaining operations asynchronously as well in its completionHandler block. The problem is the completionHandler block does not seem to run asynchronously.

Would there be a need to setup a new session manager and/or download task to accomplish this. Is there perhaps a better way to do this so the operations can be performed away from the main thread in the completionHandler block.

The reason for wanting to accomplish this is to avoid tying up the main thread in case there's a huge amount of data which needs to be assigned to the self.googleResults array or rather in a for loop using a custom class containing properties for specific key data which would eventually be added as elements to an array.

Here's the code so far...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=json"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response)
    {
        // NOTE: This code block runs asynchronously
        NSURL *docPathURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
        return [docPathURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];

    } completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error)
    {
        // NOTE: This code block does not run asynchronously
        // Would there be a need to create a new session and/or download task here to get the data from the filePath asynchronously?
        // Or is there another way to this for the following code?
        NSError *jsonSerializationErr;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:filePath];
        NSDictionary *reponseDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&jsonSerializationErr];

        // self.googleResults is an instance of (NSArray *)
        self.googleResults = [[reponseDictionary objectForKey:@"responseData"] objectForKey:@"results"];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.googleResults);
    }];
    [downloadTask resume];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean that the completion block doesn't run asynchronously?  It is invoked when the download from the server is finished. The act of loading the JSON data from the local file into the dictionary occurs in this asynchronous block invocation. As it is a local file access it shouldn't take long

Comment: Do you need to save the json data to the file system? If not you could just use `AFHTTPSessionManager` as it's simpler.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for the prompt reply. I was noticing this after setting breakpoints in both blocks for params, destination and completionHandler. The destination param's code block was showing that it's performing operations on another thread, where as the completionHandler's block was running on the main thread. Am I reading this wrong? Also I just realized that I forgot to mention the destination param in the initial post, that's what I meant by it running asynchronously and the completionHandler not running asynchronously.

Comment: You are confusing asynchronous and different threads. A method can be invoked asynchronously on the main thread.

Comment: @race_carr Yes, I am trying to make this work for an example scenario where saving the json data to a file is required.

Comment: @Paulw11 I think I see what you mean. In that case the setup as is should be okay?

Comment: Yes, I would think so.